# Getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on glGenTextures

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-2

Trying out a bit of C++ and OpenGL with SDL2 & SDL2_image, based off of http://open.gl

I'm getting the subject error once it reaches the glGenTextures call. Most of my searches have mentioned not creating a gl context yet. I have, and use multiple gl calls prior to this one succesfully. Here's what i have in my main. So

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    uniforms = std::vector<GLuint>();
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL", 100, 100, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    SDL_Event windowEvent;

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    GLuint ebo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);

    setupVertices(vbo);
    setupElementBuffer(ebo);

    GLuint fragmentShader;
    GLuint vertexShader;

    GLuint shaderProgram = compileShaders(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    bindAttributes(shaderProgram);

    GLuint tex;
    glGenTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, &tex);

    SDL_Surface *image = IMG_Load("pic.png");

    if (!image) {
        assert(false);
    }


    int mode;
    if (image->format->BytesPerPixel == 3) { // RGB 24bit
        mode = GL_RGB;
    } else if (image->format->BytesPerPixel == 4) { // RGBA 32bit
        mode = GL_RGBA;
    }

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    // ... etc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`glGenTextures()` takes as first argument a *count* to how many texture names you want to be created, and as second a pointer to an arry big enough to hold all names. You are calling

```
GLuint tex;
glGenTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, &tex);
```

So you use `GL_TEXTURE_2D` as the count, which is some quite big number, and the GL will overwrite whatever follows `tex` on your stack, resulting in the crash...

Comment: On open.gl and an sdl example i found, I'm not sure how i read that wrong. Looked over it like 10 times too haha. Must be friday :). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use this fix it: 
glGenTextures(1, &textureId);

Comment: You'll want to use the GL_TEXTURE_2D constant instead of a hard number. The constants are just numerical values, it's just easier to understand as you move forward.

Comment: @agmcleod see the other answer - the first argument is not a constant, it's a count